# Python function in an if-statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a function which returns true/false. Now I tried to use in a condicional, like this:

```
isOdd = lambda n: True if n%2 != 0 else False

if !isOdd(2): 
  print('Yey')
```

but I got `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

how could I use ! in a function like this? it looks like this only works if:

```
if isOdd(2) == False: 
  print('Yey')
```

Comment: `if not isOdd(2):`

Comment: Note that `True if n%2 != 0 else False` can be written as `n%2 != 0`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe Python uses `!` for negation like C does.  Try

```
if not isOdd(2):
```